# Set Windows Theme Settings Globally?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, thin-client

Long story short, we have a small thin client infrastructure setup using Windows 7 and XP for educational use (not Server 2008/2003).

My question is if anyone knows of a way to set the Windows theme to "Classic" for all users (for XP & 7)?  This could be a logon script, or a registry edit, anything really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [local group policy](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/force-a-specific-visual-style-for-all-users-in-windows-7) to accomplish this task. The setting will have to be applied on each workstation. The article says Windows 7 but the instructions work for XP as well.